# How to hide description, reviews and additional information on a specific wordpress category?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using this code but description, reviews and additional information hides on all products. I just need to hide these only on Australian open category.

```
function woo_remove_product_tab($tabs)
{
    unset($tabs['description']); // Remove the description tab
    unset($tabs['reviews']); // Remove the reviews tab
    unset($tabs['additional_information']); // Remove the additional information tab
    return $tabs;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tab', 98);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'storefront_post_header_categories', 6);

function storefront_post_header_categories()
{
    global $product;
    $terms = get_the_terms($product->get_id() , 'product_cat');
    if ($terms[0]->slug == 'australian-open')
    {
        dynamic_sidebar('accompanied-service');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'conditionaly_removing_product_tabs', 99 );
function conditionaly_removing_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    // Get the global product object
    global $product;

    // Get the current product ID
    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

    // Define HERE your targeted categories (Ids, slugs or names)   <===  <===  <===
    $product_cats = array( 'clothing', 'posters', 'Australian open');

    // If the current product have the same ID than one of the defined IDs in your array,… 
    // we remove the tab.
    if( has_term( $product_cats, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){

        // KEEP BELOW ONLY THE TABS YOU NEED TO REMOVE   <===  <===  <===  <===
        unset( $tabs['description'] ); // (Description tab)  
        unset( $tabs['reviews'] );     // (Reviews tab)
        unset( $tabs['additional_information'] ); // (Additional information tab)
    }
    return $tabs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sunnybhadania but i just found a solution that's also worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
function woo_remove_product_tab($tabs){
global $product;
$terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
if ($terms[0]->slug=='australian-open'){
unset($tabs['description']); // Remove the description tab
unset($tabs['reviews']); // Remove the reviews tab
unset($tabs['additional_information']); // Remove the additional information tab
}
return $tabs;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tab', 98);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'storefront_post_header_categories', 6);

function storefront_post_header_categories()
{
global $product;
$terms = get_the_terms($product->get_id() , 'product_cat');
if ($terms[0]->slug == 'australian-open')
{
    dynamic_sidebar('accompanied-service');
}
}
```